# My package works well for c++ but not for c files?

Tags: c++, c, r

I built my own function and everythings goes well unless for `.c` files.

My package has `src` folder to save my `foo.c` files in it.

```
  void foo(double *x, int *length) {
  for(int i=0; i<*length; i++) {
    x[i] = x[i]+1;
  }
}
```

I saved this simple `foo.c` file in `src` and build my package using `build` tap in Rstudio. Then I saved the wrapper R funciton inside `R` folder of the package.

```
addone <- function(x) {
  x <- as.double(x)
  .C("foo", DUP=F, x, length(x))
  return(x)
}
```

Then I got this error.

```
Error in .C("foo", DUP = F, x, length(x)) : 
  C symbol name "foo" not in load table
```

I am a mac user.

Any help please?

Comment: Both are different languages.

Comment: I Know that they are different languages but when I create my package I read that the package will able to work with both languages. @rsp

Comment: In C++ the function names are [name mangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

Comment: Take a look at the symbol table of your `foo.dylib` using [nm](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nm.1.html) utility. See if `foo` is present and how exactly does it's name look like.

Comment: @tgregory thank you so much for your comment. I think the idea is that I did not build my package in the way that it can accept the .c files. I built it using `Rcpp`.